# make main div container fix height

Tags: css

I have a div container (mapInfo-Container) containing several div blocks
and i want the container to be fix height (250px), the div container scrollable for everything more than this height.

http://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/mxt32057/11/

```
   .mapInfo-Container {
     height: 250px;
     //overflow-y: scroll;
   }
```

I tried overflow-y: scroll; but doesn' t work, think i miss something.

Can you help me out

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.mapInfo-Container` contains floated elements. To combat that use the `clearfix` property:

```
<div class="mapInfo-Container clearfix">
```

Also, use `overflow-y: auto` instead of `overflow-y: scroll;`.

Here's a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/guvrqvk3/)

Comment: Thnaks for your answer, try it, but doesn' t looks good http://jsfiddle.net/dtjmsy/mxt32057/14/

Comment: It does not look good because you have used float: right, and width: 22%. I have added a link in the question. Check that out.

Answer (score 0):

It does work. The problem in your fiddle is with the css for .mapInfo-Block. Remove the width and float to get this:

```
.mapInfo-Block {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid px;
}
```

You can also remove the div #map-info, and uncomment your other css rules in .mapInfo-Container:

```
.mapInfo-Container {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 22%;
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mxt32057/19/

Answer (score 0):

add overflow-y: scroll to mapInfo-Container class

and

add one more class to pin_0, pin_1 and pin_2 div's 
than set width: auto in it.